# is this a Django bug?

Tags: django, django-models

I created a project and within the project an app call myusers. I then created a model with the class name AllUsers. I then populated the model with data from faker.

When I go to 127.0.0.1/admin under authorization I have groups and users. Under myusers I have ‘All userss’ which is a link to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/myusers/allusers/

so, I’m just wondering if this is a minor bug. Shouldn’t it say ‘AllUsers’ and not ‘All userss’? Or did I corrupt something along the way?

Comment: No, model names are written in *singular*.

Comment: how does that apply?  All userss doesn't look singular

Comment: You rename the class to `AllUser`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, a model normally has a *singular* name, so `AllUser`, not <s>`AllUsers`</s>.

Django will, based on the name add a suffix `…s` for the *plural*. Indeed, for a model you can check the verbose name with:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.Meta.verbose_name_plural
'users'
```

For your model you can specify the singluar and plural name yourself with:

```
class AllUsers(models.Model):
    # …
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'all user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'all users'
```

But nevertheless, it is better to give the class a *singular* name. Especially since other parts, like the default for [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) is `modelname_set`, so for a `ForeignKey` of your `AllUser` model, that would look like `allusers_set`, which does not look very pleasant.

Comment: didn't noticed we can use User.Meta.verbose_name_plural (: thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should not create a model that represents a set of entities. A model should represent a single entity. Since a model should only represent a single entity, Django adds an "s" to the end in the admin to pluralize it (i.e, a model named "Car" will be "Cars" in the admin).

Of course you can change the `verbose_plural_name` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural), but the best way forward is to not continue using this technique to represent all users at all.

To represent all users you should be using a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/).